# Use spark-submit to submit a application to EC2 cluster

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I am new to Spark and I am trying to run it on EC2. I follow the tutorial on spark webpage by using spark-ec2 to launch a Spark cluster. Then, I try to use `spark-submit` to submit the application to the cluster. The command looks like this:

`./bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master spark://ec2-54-88-9-74.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7077 --executor-memory 2G --total-executor-cores 1 ./examples/target/scala-2.10/spark-examples_2.10-1.0.0.jar 100`

However, I got the following error:

`ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.`

Please let me know how to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You're seeing this issue because the master node of your spark-standalone cluster cant open a TCP connection back to the drive (on your machine).  The default mode of `spark-submit` is *client* which runs the driver on the machine that submitted it.

A new cluster mode was added to spark-deploy that submits the job to the master where it is then run on a client, removing the need for a direct connection.  Unfortunately this mode is not supported in standalone mode.

You can vote for the JIRA issue here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2260

Tunneling your connection via SSH is possible but latency would be a big issue since the driver would be running locally on your machine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm curious if you still having this issue ... But in case anyone is asking here is a brief answer. As clarified by jhappoldt, the master node of your spark-standalone cluster cant open a TCP connection back to the drive (on your local machine). Two workarounds are possible, tested and succeeded.

(1) From EC2 Management Console, create a new security group and add rules to enable TCP back and forth from your PC (public IP). (what I did was adding TCP rules inbound and outbound) ... Then add this security group to your master instance. (right click --> Networking --> Change security groups). Note: add it and don't remove the already established security groups.

This solution work well, but in your specific scenario, deploying your application from local machine to EC2 cluster, you will face further problems (resource related) so the next option is the best one

(2) Having your .jar file (or .egg) copy it to the master node using scp. You can check this link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html for information about how to do that; and deploy your application from the master node. Note: spark is already pre-insalled so you will do nothing but write the same exact command you write on your local machine from ~/spark/bin. This shall work perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Are you executing the command on your local machine, or on the created EC2 node? If you're doing it locally, make sure port 7077 is open in the security settings, as its closed to the outside by default.

Comment: I am having similar issue starting job on ec2 cluster using pyspark or spark-shell from local.  I have already add inbound rule to accept 7077 connection from everywhere.  What gives?