# PySpark in Pycharm- unable to connect to remote server

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Use Case: I want to use my laptop (using Win 7 Professional) to connect to the CentOS 6.4 master server using PyCharm.

Objective: To write the code in Pycharm on the laptop and then send the job to the server which will do the processing and should then return the result back to the laptop or to any other visualizing API.

The server and 3 namenodes already installed with pyspark and I have checked pyspark works in standalone mode on all four servers. Pyspark works in standalone mode on my laptop too.

I use the following code but I am not able to connect to the remote server.

```
    import os
    import sys
try:
    from pyspark import SparkContext
    from pyspark import SparkConf
    print ("Pyspark sucess")
except ImportError as e:
    print ("Error importing Spark Modules", e)

conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("spark://10.210.250.400:7077")
conf.setAppName("First_Remote_Spark_Program")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
print ("connection succeeded with Master",conf)
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
distData = sc.parallelize(data)
print(distData)
```

The stack trace of error is

```
        Pyspark sucess
15/08/01 14:08:24 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/08/01 14:08:24 ERROR Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:318)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:333)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:326)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:76)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.parseStaticMapping(Groups.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:77)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:240)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:255)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:232)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:718)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:703)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:605)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2162)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2162)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2162)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:301)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:61)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:234)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:214)
at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:79)
at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:68)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/08/01 14:08:25 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
15/08/01 14:08:26 WARN AppClient$ClientActor: Could not connect to akka.tcp://sparkMaster@10.210.250.400:7077: akka.remote.InvalidAssociation: Invalid address: akka.tcp://sparkMaster@10.210.250.400:7077
15/08/01 14:08:26 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@10.210.250.400:7077]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: Connection refused: no further information: /10.210.250.400:7077
15/08/01 14:08:46 WARN AppClient$ClientActor: Could not connect to akka.tcp://sparkMaster@10.210.250.400:7077: akka.remote.InvalidAssociation: Invalid address: akka.tcp://sparkMaster@10.210.250.400:7077
15/08/01 14:08:46 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@10.210.250.400:7077]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: Connection refused: no further information: /10.210.250.400:7077
15/08/01 14:09:06 WARN AppClient$ClientActor: Could not connect to akka.tcp://sparkMaster@10.210.250.400:7077: akka.remote.InvalidAssociation: Invalid address: akka.tcp://sparkMaster@10.210.250.400:7077
15/08/01 14:09:06 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@10.210.250.400:7077]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: Connection refused: no further information: /10.210.250.400:7077
15/08/01 14:09:25 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
15/08/01 14:09:25 WARN SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application ID is not initialized yet.
15/08/01 14:09:25 ERROR OneForOneStrategy: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientActor$$anonfun$receiveWithLogging$1.applyOrElse(AppClient.scala:160)
at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply$mcVL$sp(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:25)
at org.apache.spark.util.ActorLogReceive$$anon$1.apply(ActorLogReceive.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.util.ActorLogReceive$$anon$1.apply(ActorLogReceive.scala:42)
at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:118)
at org.apache.spark.util.ActorLogReceive$$anon$1.applyOrElse(ActorLogReceive.scala:42)
at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientActor.aroundReceive(AppClient.scala:61)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
15/08/01 14:09:25 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$assertNotStopped(SparkContext.scala:103)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.getSchedulingMode(SparkContext.scala:1501)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.postEnvironmentUpdate(SparkContext.scala:2005)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:543)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:61)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:234)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:214)
at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:79)
at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:68)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/ashish dutt/PycharmProjects/KafkaToHDFS/local2Remote.py", line 26, in <module>
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
File "C:\spark-1.4.0\python\pyspark\context.py", line 113, in __init__
conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
File "C:\spark-1.4.0\python\pyspark\context.py", line 165, in _do_init
self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
File "C:\spark-1.4.0\python\pyspark\context.py", line 219, in _initialize_context
return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
File "C:\spark-1.4.0\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 701, in __call__
File "C:\spark-1.4.0\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$assertNotStopped(SparkContext.scala:103)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.getSchedulingMode(SparkContext.scala:1501)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.postEnvironmentUpdate(SparkContext.scala:2005)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:543)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:61)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:234)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:214)
at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:79)
at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:68)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The spark-defaults.conf file is configured as follows

```
    #spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://ABCD01:8020/user/spark/applicationHistory
spark.eventLog.dir      hdfs://10.210.250.400:8020/user/spark/eventlog
spark.eventLog.enabled      true
spark.serializer        org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.shuffle.service.enabled   true
spark.shuffle.service.port  7337
spark.yarn.historyServer.address    http://ABCD04:18088
spark.master        spark://10.210.250.400:7077
spark.yarn.jar      local:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.2-1.cdh5.4.2.p0.2/lib/spark/assembly/lib/spark-assembly-1.3.0-cdh5.4.2-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.4.2.jar
spark.driver.extraLibraryPath   /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.2-1.cdh5.4.2.p0.2/lib/hadoop/lib/native
spark.executor.extraLibraryPath /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.2-1.cdh5.4.2.p0.2/lib/hadoop/lib/native
spark.yarn.am.extraLibraryPath  /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.2-1.cdh5.4.2.p0.2/lib/hadoop/lib/native
spark.logConf   true
```

The spark-env.sh file is configured as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
##
# Generated by Cloudera Manager and should not be modified directly
##

SELF="$(cd $(dirname $BASH_SOURCE) && pwd)"
if [ -z "$SPARK_CONF_DIR" ]; then
export SPARK_CONF_DIR="$SELF"
fi

export SPARK_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.2-1.cdh5.4.2.p0.2/lib/spark
export DEFAULT_HADOOP_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.2-1.cdh5.4.2.p0.2/lib/hadoop
#export STANDALONE_SPARK_MASTER_HOST=`ABCD01`
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=spark://10.210.250.400
export SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077
export SPARK_WEBUI_PORT=18080


### Path of Spark assembly jar in HDFS
export SPARK_JAR_HDFS_PATH=${SPARK_JAR_HDFS_PATH:-''}

export HADOOP_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME:-$DEFAULT_HADOOP_HOME}

if [ -n "$HADOOP_HOME" ]; then
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:${HADOOP_HOME}/lib/native
fi

SPARK_EXTRA_LIB_PATH=""
if [ -n "$SPARK_EXTRA_LIB_PATH" ]; then
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$SPARK_EXTRA_LIB_PATH
fi

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_CONF_DIR:-$SPARK_CONF_DIR/yarn-conf}

# This is needed to support old CDH versions that use a forked version
# of compute-classpath.sh.
export SCALA_LIBRARY_PATH=${SPARK_HOME}/lib

# Set distribution classpath. This is only used in CDH 5.3 and later.
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(paste -sd: "$SELF/classpath.txt")
```

And the slaves.sh file is configured as

```
10.210.250.401
10.210.250.402
10.210.250.403
```

Please tell me how can I connect to the remote server.

Comment: The line `conf.setMaster("spark://10.210.250.400:7077")` does not actually make a connection to the server. But it will try and create a gateway to your local JVM using Py4J (this is how pyspark works given Spark is Scala software).

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py#L44

I suggest you take away the try and except blocks, so it fails with a more verbose stack trace, and show us that.

Comment: Thank you @mattinbits for your response. I have edited the question now. Please let me know how can I resolve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Spark requires some elements of a Hadoop distribution to be present on Windows in order to work. Spark-env.sh won't help you as it is a shell script not executed on Windows. I think the solution you need is already covered here [submit .py script on Spark without Hadoop installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746395/submit-py-script-on-spark-without-hadoop-installation)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the link. It helped. So I now have the HADOOP_HOME=C:\spark-1.4.0\winutils\ I also add the same as an environment variable in PyCharm. I then reboot the computer & execute the program again. This time, the stack trace is long, so I'm posting only the error. ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.

Comment: I think you're probably hitting this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24199534/use-spark-submit-to-submit-a-application-to-ec2-cluster

Comment: thanks for the pointer. After reading it, I understand that I would need to configure the TCP port on the cluster to recognize the IP address of the laptop and configure a similar setting on the laptop to reecognise the IP address of the cluster. The question is how do I do this for the server? I am using Cloudera Manager (CDH) 5.4. I checked CDH and Hive documentation for the same but could not find anything relevant. Any pointers would be helpful. Thank you.